# Testing for associativity using the multiplication table (Cayley Table) of an operation.

Tags: group-theory, semigroups, associativity

I seem to recall that there is a relatively easy method for determining the associativity of an operation by using its Cayley table. What is it?

Comment: I disagree that this question should give context or other detail - it admits a well-defined and interesting answer. The "context" is given: "can you help me remember something?" If the answer was not well defined then I can see an issue, but as it is well-defined...

Comment: Please look through [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for advice on writing good questions on this site. In particular, a post should go beyond merely stating a problem: the motivation and background should be included, to the extent you are familiar. Posts that merely state a problem without context are often put on hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [Light's associativity test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light%27s_associativity_test) which I found on Wikipedia.

Basically,

1. Pick out the generators of the operation.
2. If $g$ is a generator define two new operations $x \circ y = (xg)y $  and $x*y=x(gy)$.
3. Form the Cayley tables of $\circ$ and $*$ for $g$.
4. If the two tables for $g$ are not identical, the original operation is NOT associative.
5. If the two tables are identical for all generators $g$, the original operation IS associative.

Notwithstanding the first comment, the link above works now, Nov 7, thanks to a kind editor.

Comment: The URL you give doesn't work. The method you describe doesn't save much work unless it's easy to find a set of generators that is much smaller than the number of elements in the structure.

Comment: @RobArthan You can always find a generating set of size at most $\log_2 n$ in $O(n^2)$ time for a group of $n$ elements described by a Cayley table.  This takes less time than the test itself.

Comment: @Qudit: that's interesting, but I was thinking  more of hand calculation for small magmas (say with less 10 elements) rather than the asymptotic complexity of the method. It's easy to come up with an $n$-element magma  that has no generating set with less than $n$ elements, so I don't see how your observation about generating sets of **groups** helps  in either case (if you know the magma is a group, then you already know it's associative.).

Comment: @RobArthan That's true.  I suppose that in the case where you were testing for associativity in order to check if it is a group, you could try to find a generating set of size at most $\log_2 n$.  If the procedure fails to find one in $O(n^2)$ time, then you know that it is not a group so you don't care if it is associative.  Otherwise, you can proceed with the test.

Comment: @Qudit: but the question (and Light's test) is about testing for associativity, not testing for all the group properties: people often do care about the associativity of operations that are not group operations. In any case, I think you need to modify your update to the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I already reverted it after you posted your initial reply.

Comment: @Qudit: I see you have undone your update to the Wikipedia page: thanks for that. Perhaps your implied conjecture about the complexity of determining whether a finite magma is a group is worth posing as an MSE question. I think you are conjecturing that it is no worse than $O(n^2 \log(n))$. Can one do better than that? Hmmm!

Comment: @RobArthan Actually, there seems to be an easier way to prove that it can be done in $O(n^2 \log n)$ time.  First, check if the magma is a quasigroup in $O(n^2)$ time.  Quasigroups also have generating sets of size at most $\log n$, so you can then apply Light's associativity test.  I am not sure if you can get rid of the $\log n$ deterministically though.  Wikipedia claims that there is a $O(n^2)$ BPP algorithm at the end of the article.

Comment: @RobArthan See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509960/complexity-of-testing-if-a-binary-operation-is-a-group

Comment: The purpose of the OP was to help people learning algebra who are having a hard time imagining doing the $216$ calculations they would have to do to check the associative law on a set of only three elements. I'm glad that it has also spurred a fascinating conversation between Rob Arthan and Qudit on a much deeper subject.